# using .find with a regular expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, sqlite

Is there anyway in ruby on rails to make a query using regexp?

Comment: See my [answer on a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839204/how-to-turn-on-regexp-in-sqlite3-and-rails-3-1/8603393#8603393) that works for Rails3 as well.

Answer (score 6):

I think it might depend on the database. I know in MySQL you can do something like:

```
Model.find(:conditions => "field REGEXP '.*'")
```

if you want a true regex, or you can use the LIKE syntax for similar string matching.

While it doesn't have regex, there's also a gem called [MetaWhere](http://metautonomo.us/projects/metawhere/) that provides more advanced finder functionality.